# Run Azure custom script extension in an ARM template as SecureExecution

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

The PowerShell command [Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/set-azurermvmcustomscriptextension?view=azurermps-4.4.0) gives the possibility to set the parameter -SecureExecution, it allows to do not write the command who will be run in the log CustomScriptHandler. It is mandatory when you passed some credentials to your script.
I would like to know if there is the same mean when I deploy a custom script extension with an ARM template.
The only documented parameters are the [following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/extensions-customscript) :
`"protectedSettings": {
            "commandToExecute": "myExecutionCommand",
            "storageAccountName": "myStorageAccountName",
            "storageAccountKey": "myStorageAccountKey"
        }`

Answer (score 0):

`"commandToExecute"` is the parameter you are looking for. it defines what gets passed to the extension.

ps. everything under protected settings gets uncrypted before execution

Comment: Sure I pass the parameter of my script in the `commandToExecute` but I'm looking how to specify to the extension to do not write the commandToExecute content in the log "CustomScriptHandler" when I use an aRM template. 
When I use PowerShell with the command "Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension" to execute my script with the custom script extension, I set the parameter "-SecureExecution" and the extension do not write my command in the log "CustomScriptHandler".
When I define my custom script extension on an ARM template command is write in clear in my log.

Comment: you are mistaken, it doesnt

Comment: I just tested another time it and I can assure you that parameters who have been passed appear in the log.

Comment: how did you test it, you need to remove the extension before testing

Comment: I makle a new deployent each time. I use this code for my extension in my ARM template : 
https://gist.github.com/YoannGUILLO/10d83afa9bd1613e4e204512a7057630
The script is correctly executed but the log "C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.9\CustomScriptHandler.log" contains my commandToExecute in clear :(

Comment: like i said, you `commandtoexecute` is NOT under `protectedsettings`, its under `settings`